# Using a promise to wait for function called and finish doing what it suppose before continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise

I am calling a function to load some file, this function is getting called from other places too..

for this section of code to run successfully `searchconfig.js` must load before

What I want to achieve is, for this call to finish loading `searchconfig.js` and just then continue with the other code and if error occurred, to log it:

```
loadRemoteFile("Search/" + Search.Configuration.PathToConfigurable + "/Configurable/searchconfig.js");
```

### Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    if (Search.Configuration && Search.Configuration.PathToConfigurable) {
        // the file that is necessary for the code to run successfully
        loadRemoteFile("Search/" + Search.Configuration.PathToConfigurable + "/Configurable/searchconfig.js");
    }

    setTimeout(function () {

        // anchor for injecting the  results
        $('body').prepend("<div id='search-results' class='container'></div>")

        for (var configItem in tempConfig) {
            Search.Configuration[configItem] = tempConfig[configItem];
        }

        var configsToCheckForSlash = ["FullPathToConfigurableFolder", "pathToSearch", "PathToConfigurable", "SearchServiceURL", "ThumbnailsURL", "CMSThumbnailsURL", "PreviewBaseURL"];

        for (var x = 0; x < configsToCheckForSlash.length; x++) {
            Search.Configuration[configsToCheckForSlash[x]] = addForwardSlashToSearchConfigSettings(Search.Configuration[configsToCheckForSlash[x]]);
            _log(Search.Configuration[configsToCheckForSlash[x]])
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < Search.Configuration.pagesToAvoid.length; x++) {
            var pagesToAvoid = Search.Configuration.pagesToAvoid[x].toLowerCase();
            if (location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(pagesToAvoid) > -1) {
                _log("Search loader abandoned. Please check settings if this is not intended.");
                return;
            }
        }

        $("head").append(Search.Configuration.requiredFiles);

        //pick implementation points  
        Search.Configuration.anchorToUseForMainSearch = $("#search-results");

        if (!Search.Configuration.anchorToUseForMainSearch.length) {
            _log("The search implementation could not find a suitable place to place the search, aborting.");
            return;
        }

        searchIsExpanded = false;
        writeSearchHTML();
    }, 400);
});
```

### loadRemoteFile function

```
function loadRemoteFile(filename, loadIntoHeader){ 
        filetype = filename.match(".css") ? "css" : "js";

        if (filetype=="js"){ 
            if(!loadIntoHeader){
                var script   = document.createElement("script");
                script.type  = "text/javascript";
                script.src   = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(script);          
            }else{
                ...             
            }           
        }else if (filetype=="css"){ 
            ...
        }
}
```

Comment: easiest way would be to include the script in your HTML before you call it. That way when you have `$();` or `document.ready` the script would have loaded up before executing whatever. Have you thought about using a CDN?

Comment: the script is actually script in CDN. what do you mean by saying "easiest way would be to include the script in your HTML before you call it"

Comment: @N. Ivanov AFAIU the OP need **conditional** loading. So `script` tag is not an option in this case

Comment: @N.Ivanov this is what the code suppose to do, but for time to time (i think it is because `searchconfig.js` is on CDN), and my app loads other things beside that ..
because of that i am trying to implement a solution with a promise involve.. that will insure the file loading prior to ruining the code

Comment: Sorry, must have misunderstood you. Hope you find a solution

Comment: `i am trying to implement a solution with a promise` - no, as you are not using promises in your code at all, so, you haven't really tried to use promises

Comment: @JaromandaX, sorry for the confusion- i wanted to know how to do it and if its a good solution

Comment: @E.Meir Nothing can make an function call block until an asynchronous process is finished. Promises just simplify waiting with a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up using is to wait for the file loading.

What I want to achieve is to finish loading `searchconfig.js` and just then continue with the other code:

```
 function when_external_loaded(callback) {
        // means searchconfig.js is loaded,
        // we should restrict the number of times we check 
        // if the parameter exist or restrict the max time for checking it
        if (typeof x.pagesToAvoid === 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(function () {
                when_external_loaded(callback);
            }, 10); // wait 10 ms
        } else { callback(); }
    }
```

and then in:

```
(document).ready(function(){
    when_external_loaded(function () {
     // place all the code that you want to occur after the file has been loaded
    }
});
```

What will happen is Only when `x.pagesToAvoid !== 'undefined')` means that `searchconfig.js` was loaded, we it will load the function calls the callback function.

Bear in mind that you should restrict the time of checking the file existing, cause if the file dont exist this will try forever (for me its OK, cause the existence of the file is not depend on nothing and he will be in that place).

I didn't use the `promise` solution, cause i misunderstood something. the `promise` only return true if happen and false if not. 
So when the file was tried to load (but it didn't load yet to memory) the `promise` will be true.. and it wasn't enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want  loadRemoteFile to return a Promise?

```
function loadRemoteFile(filename, loadIntoHeader){ 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        filetype = filename.match(".css") ? "css" : "js";

        if (filetype=="js"){ 
            if(!loadIntoHeader){
                var script   = document.createElement("script");
                script.type  = "text/javascript";
                script.src   = filename;
                script.onload = resolve;
                script.onerror = reject;
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }else{
                // mystery code
            }           
        } else {
            // more mystery code
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
loadRemoteFile("Search/" + Search.Configuration.PathToConfigurable + "/Configurable/searchconfig.js").then(function() {
    // what to do on success
}).catch(function() {
    // what to do on failure
});
```

Alternative use (this also uses the "promisified" `loadRemoteFile` above

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (async function() {
        // place **ALL** your code inside the IIFE inside .ready callback
        if (Search.Configuration && Search.Configuration.PathToConfigurable) {
            // the file that is necessary for the code to run successfully
            try {
                await loadRemoteFile("Search/" + Search.Configuration.PathToConfigurable + "/Configurable/searchconfig.js");
            } catch(error) {
                // do your error handling here
            }
        }
        // execution here starts after the above loadRemoteFile finishes
        // or the condition is false
    })();
});
```

Comment: yes, i want- and what about the other code? how do i call it? how do i wait for the promise to run successfully and how do i catch the error if something happened?

Comment: @E.Meir - added usage

Comment: i am getting the warning in console - "h1.js:25 Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error" when i click this warning - its refer me to "...config.js").then(functi..."

Comment: in Visual studio, in the `loadRemoteFile` function- there is a waning in the last `}` that says `(JS) ',' expected`

Comment: in the code you published `return new Promise(` "(" is not closed

Comment: but still i am getting this warning in console `jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: `jQuery.Deferred` - sorry, but nothing I've posted has even the slightest to do with jQueery, so ... don't know

Comment: when i am clicking this warning in the console- it opens up the line `loadRemoteFile(....searchconfig.js").then(function() {...`

Comment: my code does not. If you are getting a jquery error, then it's nothing to do with my code

Comment: `loadRemoteFile` function is also getting called from other places.. will it still work as it did? or the new `return new Promise(function` in the function will act differently?

Comment: `will it still work as it did?` - well, instead of returning `undefined` it'll return a Promise - so, it won't break existing code - of course, if you think the code in this answer can be used without `.then` - that's a problem

Comment: yes- the `loadRemoteFile` function is getting called also without `then`. so it won't work for the other calls?

Comment: correct, as loading the script is an asynchronous process, there is little (i.e. nothing) you can do to turn this into a synchronous one

Comment: so how do you suggest the the app will wait for `searchconfig.js` to load? * consider that the `loadRemoteFile` function is also heavily used without promises

Comment: `// what to do on success` kinda says it all

Comment: I've added a different usage pattern you may like

Comment: The "different usage pattern" that you have just published is not using `then` syntax- so that means that `loadRemoteFile` should be edited also (to remove the `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)...`)

Comment: no, it's using async/await - which is an alternative (sugary) way of using promises - so, the code is correct - see where I wrote *this **also** uses the "promisified" `loadRemoteFile` above* ... I wasn't just typing that for giggles, I'm pretty sure I know what I'm talking about

Comment: i will try it now to see if work ok, in that way.. how can i use `catch` in case of failure?

Comment: and what about the calls from other places to `loadRemoteFile`, they will still work ? even that the function returns a `promise` and i am not calling it with `then` syntax from other places..

Comment: i tried to place a break-point in the ready function, to see what;s happen, `$(document).ready(async function () {
    debugger;` but it doen't even get load

Comment: `it doen't even get load` - what is "it" that doesn't load? the external script? or this script? any errors in the console? what browser are you using? does it support async/await?

Comment: "it" is this script, and i use chrome- latest version

Comment: yeah, it seems jQuery doesn't like async functions in document ready! Another reason to loathe it

Answer (score 0):

First things first: your loadRemoteFile function needs to return promise to calling function (or you can use a callback function, alternatively) to ensure that calling function post-scripts are executed only after loadRemoteFile has done loading script. So, something like below:

```
var filesList = {};

function loadRemoteFile(filename, callback) {
 if(filesList[filename]) {
  callback();
 }else {
  filesList[filename] = true;
  filetype = filename.match(".css") ? "css" : "js";

        if (filetype=="js"){ 
            if(!loadIntoHeader){
                var script   = document.createElement("script");
                script.type  = "text/javascript";
                script.src   = filename;
                script.onload = resolve;
                script.onerror = reject;
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }else{
                // mystery code
            }           
        } else {
            // more mystery code
        }
  callback();
 }
}
```

Now, in your functions, always call loadRemoteFile function with the callback

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 loadRemoteFile('config-file-path', function() {
 }
})
```

An improvement would be to check in the among the loaded list of scripts for the request file, instead of maintaining an array of filenames. But it's all a part of code optimization;  I hope this gives you the idea.